# Angular's $scope doesn't work within PayPal methods promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

In PayPal promises, my `$scope` seems to be broken:

```
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

  paypal.request.post(execute_payment_url)
    .then(function(data) {

      $rootScope.loader = true; // no response?!

      if (data.payment.state === 'approved') {
        alert('hey!') // worked

        $location.path('/signup/').search({ // no response
          email: data.payment.payer.payer_info.email
        });
      }

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      alert('error')
    }).finally(function() {
      $rootScope.loader = false;
    })
}
```

I have no clue why, `$rootscope` and `$location` have already been injected in my controller. When I call `console.log($location)`, I can see the object is there.

Comment: try using the arrow function in the promise

Comment: @LunZhang don't want to try es6, have to support old browser.

Comment: Can you please post the full controller code, or at least the code that demonstrates how the `$rootScope` and `$location` services are being injected? Also, your routes declaration code and how you are using `$rootScope.loader` in other parts of the app.

Comment: @GPicazo http://pastebin.com/RLU14scV

Comment: @GPicazo You can ignore $rootscope, it should work for $location.

Comment: Can you also include code showing how you are declaring your routes? I am going to guess that the issue might be that you need to remove the trailing `/` from your path: `$location.path('/signup')....`

Comment: @GPicazo tried that, it has nothing to do with the path value,.

Comment: something is wrong with the scope when my rootscope.loader did not do anything after i move it to the paypal's block.

Comment: Tri injecting `$timeout` into the controller, and wrap the above code with `$timeout(function() { <code inside "paypal.request.post(execute_payment_url)" success function>  });`

Comment: I see two unrelated issues here.  First, you are setting `$rootScope.loader = true;` in your `.then`, only to *immediately* set it to false in the `.finally`.  The second issue seems to be with the callback itself, `.then` returns a response object, not just the data object, so you should use `function(response) .... response.data.payment.... `.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the PayPal promise is not an AngularJS `$q` Service promise. `$q` Service promises are integrated with the AngularJS framework digest cycle. It can be brought into the `$q` Service promise event queue with `$q.when`.

```
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

  //paypal.request.post(execute_payment_url)
  $q.when(paypal.request.post(execute_payment_url))
    .then(function(data) {

      $rootScope.loader = true; // no response?!

      if (data.payment.state === 'approved') {
        alert('hey!') // worked

        $location.path('/signup/').search({ // no response
          email: data.payment.payer.payer_info.email
        });
      }

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      alert('error')
    }).finally(function() {
      $rootScope.loader = false;
    })
}
```

> ### $q.when
>
> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.

-- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when).

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that you are using the paypal library instead of the angular $http service to make the request. Because of that, angular does not know it needs to update data. In order to force it to, you can $apply the changes manually:

```
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
  paypal.request.post(execute_payment_url)
    .then(function(data) {
      $rootScope.$apply(function() {

        $rootScope.loader = true; // no response?!

        if (data.payment.state === 'approved') {
          alert('hey!') // worked

          $location.path('/signup/').search({ // no response
            email: data.payment.payer.payer_info.email
          });
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      alert('error')
    }).finally(function() {
      $rootScope.$apply(function() { $rootScope.loader = false; });
    })
}
```

[[Update]]
Moved the $apply statements inside the success/finally callbacks.

Comment: I think that it should be done on the inner promise resolve function (`paypal.request.post(execute_payment_url`)

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. I've updated the success/finally callbacks